# Perform search-replace on OpenDocument files keeping the formatting

Tags: python, linux

I want to perform search and replace on a OpenDocument or OpenOffice.org file through a python script. I also do not want to lose the formatting information.

I looked up the web with the help of Google and stumbled upon [ODFPy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/odfpy), a nice solution for manipulating OpenDocument Files. But, I still could not perform search and replace by keeping the formatting information corrent.

Can I be helped please?